# Binding Popup from database to a marker

Tags: php, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to add popup to markers from database. Markers are showing unable to add title to popup.

```
        function add_markers(coordinates) {

            var geojson = (saved_markers == coordinates ? saved_markers : '');

            console.log(geojson);
            // add markers to map
            geojson.forEach(function (marker) {
                console.log(marker);
                // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
                new mapboxgl.Marker()
                    .setLngLat(marker)
                    .addTo(map);
            });

        }
```

Fetching from database

```
    $sqldata = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT proj_title, proj_location, start_fyear, complete_fyear, lng, 
       lat FROM t_capital_projects ");

    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqldata)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
        $title[] = $r['proj_title'];
        $proj_location[] = ['proj_location'];
        $start_year[] = ['start_fyear'];
        $complete_year[] = ['complete_fyear'];

    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
     
     }
```